# Failed to create the part's controls: StructuredTextEditor

Tags: java, forms, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, xml-editor

I am trying to get hold of XML editor for my RCP application. My simple aim is to show SCXML files with source and design. I tried few ways and nothing seems working.

Right now I am trying to run below approach

https://github.com/Pontesegger/codeandme/blob/master/Code%20%26%20Me%20Blog/form_editor_with_xml_source_view.zip

```
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.DocumentEvent;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.IDocument;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.IDocumentListener;
import org.eclipse.ui.IEditorInput;
import org.eclipse.ui.IEditorSite;
import org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException;
import org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor;
import org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.IFormPage;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.FileEditorInput;
import org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.IDocumentProvider;
import org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor;

public class SampleEditor extends FormEditor {

    private StructuredTextEditor fSourceEditor;
    private int fSourceEditorIndex;

    /** Keeps track of dirty code from source editor. */
    private boolean fSourceDirty = false;

    @Override
    public void init(final IEditorSite site, final IEditorInput input) throws PartInitException {
        super.init(site, input);

        // TODO: load your model here
    }

    @Override
    protected void addPages() {
        fSourceEditor = new StructuredTextEditor();
        fSourceEditor.setEditorPart(this);

        try {
            // add form pages
            addPage(new FirstForm(this, "firstID", "First Page"));

            // add source page
            fSourceEditorIndex = addPage(fSourceEditor, getEditorInput());
            setPageText(fSourceEditorIndex, "Source");
        } catch (final PartInitException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // add listener for changes of the document source
        getDocument().addDocumentListener(new IDocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void documentAboutToBeChanged(final DocumentEvent event) {
                // nothing to do
            }

            @Override
            public void documentChanged(final DocumentEvent event) {
                fSourceDirty = true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void doSaveAs() {
        // not allowed
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSaveAsAllowed() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void doSave(final IProgressMonitor monitor) {
        if (getActivePage() != fSourceEditorIndex)
            updateSourceFromModel();

        fSourceEditor.doSave(monitor);
    }

    @Override
    protected void pageChange(final int newPageIndex) {
        // check for update from the source code
        if ((getActivePage() == fSourceEditorIndex) && (fSourceDirty))
            updateModelFromSource();

        // check for updates to be propagated to the source code
        if (newPageIndex == fSourceEditorIndex)
            updateSourceFromModel();

        // switch page
        super.pageChange(newPageIndex);

        // update page if needed
        final IFormPage page = getActivePageInstance();
        if (page != null) {
            // TODO update form page with new model data
            page.setFocus();
        }
    }

    private void updateModelFromSource() {
        // TODO update source code for source viewer using new model data
        fSourceDirty = false;
    }

    private void updateSourceFromModel() {
        // TODO update source page from model
        // getDocument().set("new source code");
        fSourceDirty = false;
    }

    private IDocument getDocument() {
        final IDocumentProvider provider = fSourceEditor.getDocumentProvider();
        return provider.getDocument(getEditorInput());
    }

    private IFile getFile() {
        final IEditorInput input = getEditorInput();
        if (input instanceof FileEditorInput)
            return ((FileEditorInput) input).getFile();

        return null;
    }

    private String getContent() {
        return getDocument().get();
    }
}
```

```
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.ui.forms.IManagedForm;
import org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor;
import org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormPage;
import org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.FormToolkit;
import org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.ScrolledForm;

public class FirstForm extends FormPage {

    /**
     * Create the form page.
     *
     * @param id
     * @param title
     */
    public FirstForm(final String id, final String title) {
        super(id, title);
    }

    /**
     * Create the form page.
     *
     * @param editor
     * @param id
     * @param title
     * @wbp.parser.constructor
     * @wbp.eval.method.parameter id "Some id"
     * @wbp.eval.method.parameter title "Some title"
     */
    public FirstForm(final FormEditor editor, final String id, final String title) {
        super(editor, id, title);
    }

    /**
     * Create contents of the form.
     *
     * @param managedForm
     */
    @Override
    protected void createFormContent(final IManagedForm managedForm) {
        final FormToolkit toolkit = managedForm.getToolkit();
        final ScrolledForm form = managedForm.getForm();
        form.setText("First Editor Page");
        final Composite body = form.getBody();
        toolkit.decorateFormHeading(form.getForm());
        toolkit.paintBordersFor(body);
    }
}
```

Plugin.xml

```
 <editor
            class="generic.layer.editor.v2.SampleEditor"
            default="false"
            id="generic.layer.editor.v2.editor1"
            name="name">
         <contentTypeBinding
               contentTypeId="generic.layer.editor.v2.content-type1">
         </contentTypeBinding>
      </editor>
   </extension>
 <extension
       point="org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes">
    <content-type
          base-type="org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml"
          file-extensions="scxml"
          id="generic.layer.editor.v2.content-type1"
          name="name"
          priority="normal">
    </content-type>
```

And call to the editor from my view

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
                                    IStorage storage = new StringStorage((String)o);
                                       IStorageEditorInput input = new StringInput(storage);
                                       try {
                                        page.openEditor(input, "generic.layer.editor.v2.editor1");
                                    } catch (PartInitException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
```

This is the error I am getting right now

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-09-27 15:56:32.129
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor.createCombinedPreferenceStore(StructuredTextEditor.java:1521)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor.initializeEditor(StructuredTextEditor.java:2768)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.<init>(AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor.<init>(TextEditor.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor.<init>(StructuredTextEditor.java:1151)
    at generic.layer.editor.v2.SampleEditor.addPages(SampleEditor.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.createPages(FormEditor.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:355)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:990)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:955)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:399)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:992)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:661)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:738)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:716)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1293)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.lambda$0(LazyStackRenderer.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4889)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:769)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1188)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3261)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$25(WorkbenchPage.java:3176)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3158)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3117)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3098)
    at generic.layer.editor.v2.SCXMLView$1$1.run(SCXMLView.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4213)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3820)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at generic.layer.editor.v2.Application.start(Application.java:21)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
Sep 27, 2019 3:56:32 PM generic.layer.editor.v2.PropertyView$2$1 run
INFO: Receiving event for transformation propoerties:
```

Comment: A method is being called in that line on an object that's `null`. Debug your application instead of Running it--what's `null` that's not supposed to be?

Comment: Active workbench window will be null if running in a non-UI thread. The way around this is to pass needed UI elements to the job before scheduling, or run in a UI thread.